# Sorting on two fields on a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two field "display_at_bottom", "date_added" in user table.

```
user_id     display_at_bottom       date_added
-------     -----------------       ----------
1                   0               2014-10-15
2                   0               2014-10-14
3                   1               2014-10-13
4                   0               2014-10-16
5                   1               2014-10-16
```

I want to sort records desc on date_added field. I also want to display records which is marked as 1 in "display_at_bottom" at the bottom, no matter what date it contain. I want output like this.

```
user_id     display_at_bottom       date_added
-------     -----------------       ----------
4                   0               2014-10-16
1                   0               2014-10-15
2                   0               2014-10-14
3                   1               2014-10-13
5                   1               2014-10-16
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to order by two columns, first the `display_at_bottom` and then the date:

```
order by display_at_bottom, date_added desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM *your database* ORDER BY date_added DESC;
```

or if you want the display_at_bottom:

```
SELECT * FROM *your database* ORDER BY display_at_bottom DESC;
```